# Publish updated/new apk with new keystore

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, apk, keystore

So I have learnt my lesson in backing up my keystore and the new one is now safely tucked away from now on.  { and yes I have looked for the old one for ages :-( }

I need to un-publish my current app and so I can reuse the app name and create a new app version 1 with the new keystore I have created.

I can only un-publish my app and not delete it as Google need to keep it as unpublished for legal reasons etc etc so understand that.

How do I create a new app with the same name as right now play store says that the name is already in use.

Still digging and investigating a solution but any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: So whats a solution.  If I just change the .com.companyName.appName can I still use the same app Name?

Comment: @timv Yes, that's correct

Answer (score 4):

So after talking with Google support I really wanted to get the correct solution that only changed what needed to be changed and leave what could be left alone.

So for all the folk out there like me who lost their keystore file, here is the necessary steps for republishing your app where you have lost your keystore.

1. Unplubish your app.
   So under ALL APPLICATIONS you see this and the app shows as Unpublished under Status.
   [image]
2. Change the name of your unpublished app.
   Here i just added the word old to the app name.
   [image]
3. Rebuild your app with a new package name as follows:
   if the current package name is com.mycom.myapp then use a new one such as com.mynewapp.myapp
4. Make a new keystore and when they say to KEEP IT SAFE they really do mean it, KEEP IT SAFE.

( I am still in the process of republishing the app so I will update my answer with more info once published.)

Answer (score 3):

Google Play allows many apps to have the same title. However, the application package for each app needs to be unique within Google Play. This is the package attribute value that you provide for the `<manifest>` tag in the AndroidManifest.xml file of your project. The package name serves as a unique identifier for the application.

For example:
com.yourwebsite.yourappname or com.yourwebsite.yoursuitename.yourappname.

Here's the link for Android manifest :http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#package

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try and appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I create a new app with the same name as right now play store
>   says that the name is already in use.

You cannot use the same name or package name. An app once published cannot be deleted and the package name is forbidden going forward once published to avoid re-publishing of banned/forbidden apps.

Same name can be used by a different developer but not by the same developer who already has an app with that name. (This is my understanding from a time when i entered the same name by mistake)

You will need to use a different package name and app name. But, if it was banned there is a high probability that it will survive with the new package name for long. It will get banned again and probably also lead to banning of the developer account. Be careful.

Comment: No nothing like that, its a straight forward app that was published just fine, but I lost my keystore so need to publish the app again.   Seems like I need to recreate the whole developer side too, but doable.  Either way, take home message is KEEP the keystore safe!!  I have learnt my lesson.